# Last row of QTableWidget.itemAt() returns None instead of QTableWidgetItem

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am making a GUI using PyQt5 that displays data in table. I want to get the item at a specific cursor position when 'Right-Click" is pressed. This is achieved using the contextMenuEvent function and works for all rows except the last. When clicking the last row of the table, it prints "None" instead of the QTableWidgetItem Object.

I'm confused as to why its returning None when it should return the last QTableWidgetItem.

I've tried tinkering with the event.pos() and changing it to globalPos(), thinking maybe the coordinates are wrong, but nothing has worked.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class CollectWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self): # window properties
        super().__init__()

        # create window
        self.setGeometry(0,0, 800, 600)
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        # create table display 
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.table.setColumnCount(7)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Exam Remark", "Preop", "Appt Time", "Patient Details", "Exam", "Ward", "Bed"])

        # load data into table
        self.getData()

        # show the window
        self.showMaximized()

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):

        print (self.table.itemAt(event.pos()))

    def getData(self):

        # retrieve data from database
        result = [('Phil', 'Jones', 11256675, '08/09/1994', '09:40', '10:00', '09', '912', 'CT Pulmonary Angio', None, 'A', 'Clark Bed Bay', 'Arrived'), 
        ('Max', 'Stevenson', 11256676, '07/05/1965', '09:10', '09:30', '12', '1231', 'ECHO TTE', 'Rebook for Tommorow', 'PX', 'Tulloch 3 Bed Bay', 'Procedure Cancelled'), 
        ('Alfred', 'Bosch', 11256677, '01/01/1976', '09:40', '10:00', 'CLK9', 'CLK914', 'MRI Lumbar Spine', None, 'NP', 'Clark Bed Bay', 'Nurse Preparation'), 
        ('Gwenda', 'Gull', 11256678, '17/06/1956', '08:55', '09:15', 'EC', '03', 'XRAY Chest', None, 'F', 'Tulloch 2 Bed Bay', 'Exam Finished'), 
        ('John', 'Stalwort', 11256679, '15/07/1977', '12:00', '12:30', 'CLK8', 'CLK831', 'MRI Whole Spine', None, None, None, 'Created'), 
        ('Peter', 'Fitzgibbons', 11256680, '17/04/1944', '12:00', '12:30', '07', '733', 'CT Chest Abdomen Pelvis', 'Hold', None, None, 'Created'), 
        ('Julie', 'Bishop', 11256681, '15/6/1977', '12:30', '12:45', '09', '931', 'XRAY Chest', '', '', '', 'Created')]

        self.table.setRowCount(0)
        # plug data into table
        for row_number, row_data in enumerate(result):
            self.table.insertRow(row_number)

            examRemark = '' if row_data[9] is None else row_data[9]
            preopTime = '' if row_data[4] is None else row_data[4]
            apptTime = '' if row_data[5] is None else row_data[5]
            patientDetails = row_data[1] + ", " + row_data[0] + " - " + row_data[3] + " - " + str(row_data[2]) 
            exam = '' if row_data[8] is None else row_data[8]
            ward = '' if row_data[6] is None else row_data[6]
            bed = '' if row_data[7] is None else row_data[7]

            self.table.setItem(row_number, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(examRemark)))
            self.table.setItem(row_number, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(preopTime)))
            self.table.setItem(row_number, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(apptTime)))
            self.table.setItem(row_number, 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(patientDetails)))
            self.table.setItem(row_number, 4, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(exam)))
            self.table.setItem(row_number, 5, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(ward)))
            self.table.setItem(row_number, 6, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(bed)))


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = CollectWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`event.pos()` contains the position of your cursor in your `QMainWindow` coordinate system. The method `itemAt` expects a position in the coordinate system of your table viewport.

You have to map the position in your event to the right coordinate system with something like that:

```
    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        positionRelativeToMainWindow = event.pos()
        positionRelativeToViewport = self.table.viewport().mapFrom(self, positionRelativeToMainWindow)
        i = self.table.itemAt(positionRelativeToViewport)
        print(i.data(Qt.DisplayRole))
```

Comment: This works perfectly thanks. I guessed it was something to do with the coordinates but just couldn't figure out how to map them.